# api.fda.gov is failing security check

Tags: openfda

This server couldn't prove that it's api.fda.gov; its security certificate is from *.fr.cloud.gov. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Comment: Please detail how you are connecting, whether it is the first time you try, or from when it started happening.

Answer (score 2):

We had a series of brief outages last week while adapting our networking to support an upstream change. The issue is now resolved and uptime is restored to our normal consistency. Thank you for your patience and my apologies for any problems this created for our users.

Regards,
Violet Wren
openFDA Tech Lead

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue. I'm accessing the API through the Python requests module. I fixed the issue by adding the argument `verify=False` in my request (full code below). I'm pretty sure this is bad practice, but I think it's fine for a trusted source like the FDA for a small number of API calls (which is my case). Someone please correct me if I'm wrong. The following is my call for information  about a particular NDC, which generated the error you've mentioned.

```
r = requests.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:{NDC}')
```

When I change it to:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:{NDC}', verify=False)
```

it works. Hope that helps until they fix the issue.

EDIT: It seems to work now. No need to have `verify=False` if you're using requests in Python.